# Is there a way to search for more than one keyword in a search bar in JSoup?

Tags: java, jsoup, keyword, keyword-search

Java Code for one keyword-search

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.medhelp.org/search")
                .data("query", "diabetes")
                .get();
```

Is there a way to map more than one keyword e.g diabetes or/and acne, in the search bar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to submit array using Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190348/how-to-submit-array-using-jsoup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special. Just type your query directly with a space:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.medhelp.org/search")
               .data("query", "diabetes acne")
               .get();
```

Alternatively, instead of passing data you could just take a look how the browser transforms entered input into URL parameters:

## [image]

and you can just GET this URL without sending data, so it will be enough to do:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.medhelp.org/search?utf8=✓&query=diabetes+acne")
               .get();
```